Cross section of isotopes and element
In nuclear physics, what is the cross-sectional relationship between elements and isotopes?
For example, I found Uranium's absorption cross section is 7.59b (barn)
and Uranium 235's absorption cross section is 687b and Uranium 238's absorption cross section is 2.73b. (In this case, I'll assume there is no other isotopes of Uranium.)
I can't understand why there is such relationship between 7.59, 687, and 2.73;
7.59 = 687 * M(235U)/M(U) * 0.0072 + 2.73 * M(238U)/M(U) * 0.9927
Here, 0.0072 and 0.9927 is abundance, and M(U) is Uranium's atomic weight.

What don't you understand? It's a weighted mean. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean
